# Power Bi Desktop Snowflake Connector with SQL Query

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, powerbi-desktop

Our company is adopting Snowflake and I am trying to test the various connectors. I see the standard Snowflake connector if Power Bi Desktop has an optional method to include a SQL query. However, any attempt to use this results in an error: "The key didn't match any rows in the table." Is this something that is possible, or do I need to go the ODBC route with a gateway? I was hoping we wouldn't need a gateway. If I do not include the SQL query then I can connect smoothly to the tables needed, but queries are always needed...

[image: Example of connector setup]
[image: Error Message]

Comment: Any SQL statement get's this error that work in Snowflake. 

I just had an example of:

SELECT
*
from Schema.table;

Comment: What does the query history at Snowflake side show?

Comment: Please note that query is wrapped using outerquery, so avoid `;` at the end of the SQL query in Power BI

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Nothing hits on the snowflake activity side. It's an almost instant error message. I took out the `;` and it still has the error.

Comment: Then you should start with checking the Server/Warehouse/Role/Database name.  Have you tried to provide database/warehouse name all upper-case?

Comment: That was it, didn't realize database was case sensitive. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest checking Snowflake [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history) to confirm if any query is executed at Snowflake's side.

If not then the connection details like database/warehouse name/role should be checked(**case sensitive**)

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/common-issues#error-the-key-didnt-match-any-rows-in-the-table and https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2020/04/06/understanding-the-the-key-didnt-match-any-rows-in-the-table-error-in-power-query-in-power-bi-or-excel/